# Множественные операции в PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, интерфейс, копирование

Смотрел видео [Laravel 9 и Vue 3 SPA интернет магазин 4. Установка AdminLTE для laravel через composer и вручную](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ0HMlQbT7s&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t9UEjGQHafQB751mf5cwqNv&index=5). См. с 12:00-12:40. Как (с помощью каких комбинаций клавиш) в PhpStorm можно производить множественный ввод, множественное выделение, множественное копирование и множественную вставку?

**P. S.** Alt+G для выделения href не сработало (если я конечно правильно все сделал).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо ALT+J а не G)

но вообще там ещё можно

- ALT + зажать левый клик и провести мышкой по соседним строкам
- ALT + SHIFT + левый клилк
- СТRL + ALT + SHIFT + J - выбрать все результаты поиска (на это есть ещё кнопка в UI поиска)

документация https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html (на русском почему-то не нашёл)